# Limit the x axis in matplotlib python

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, matplotlib, graph

I have code that produces a live graph, updating every few seconds.  It all functions EXACTLY as I want other than a single issue, the x axis keeps adding new values but never removing old ones

in the example code below, because I limit the dataframe to 6 columns, I expect to never see more than 6 measurements represented on my x-axis.  Instead, the graph continues to update and eventually the poiunts are too close together.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import random
import time
measurements = ['abc','bcd','afr','reg','wow']
counter = 0
figure = pyplot.figure()
measurement_frame = pd.DataFrame(index = measurements)
def get_live(counter2, col_num):
    measurement_frame.iat[counter2,col_num] = random.randint(50,80)
def add_to_dataframe():
    global measurement_frame
    #timey = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    timey = datetime.now().time()
    if measurement_frame.shape[1] == 6:
        measurement_frame.drop(measurement_frame.columns[0], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    measurement_frame[timey] = measurements
    col_num = measurement_frame.shape[1]-1
    print(col_num)
    counter2 = 0
    for item in measurements:
        t = threading.Thread(target=get_live, args=(counter2, col_num,))
        t.start()
        counter2 = counter2 +1
    t.join()
    print(measurement_frame.columns[0])
    time.sleep(1)
def update(frame):
    add_to_dataframe()
    x_data = measurement_frame.columns
    print(x_data[0])
    y1_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[0]]
    y2_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[1]]
    y3_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[2]]
    y4_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[3]]
    y5_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[4]]
    line, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y1_data, '-', color = 'b')
    line2, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y2_data, '-', color = 'g')
    line3, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y3_data, '-', color = 'r')
    line4, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y4_data, '-', color = 'm')
    line5, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y5_data, '-', color = 'y')
    line.set_data(x_data, y1_data)
    line2.set_data(x_data, y2_data)
    line3.set_data(x_data, y3_data)
    line4.set_data(x_data, y4_data)
    line5.set_data(x_data, y5_data)
    figure.gca().set_xlim(x_data[0])
    figure.gca().autoscale()
    print(figure.gca().get_xlim())
    return line, line2, line3, line4, line5,
animation = FuncAnimation(figure, update, interval=1000)
pyplot.show()
```

What I need is that after the dataframe reaches maximum size, the far left measurements are removed, so as to not exceed a set number of measurements on the screen at once.  Note that the dataframe already drops unneeded columns before adding a new one when it reaches a certain size, but my graph does not reflect that

Comment: Does the [set_xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) method help in this case?

Comment: I believe it COULD help if my time wasnt a string.  I dont think it understands how to use it.  Do you know if it can interpret date time objects

Comment: can you show the output of `pyplot.get_xlim()`?

Comment: im note sure my output is what you are looking for, or you will understand it while it isnt running, so I editted my code above so you can run it locally

Answer (score 2):

using autoscale tries to keep old data in view.  If you drop autoscale and use

```
figure.gca().set_xlim(left =x_data[0], right = datetime.now().time())
```

it works as intended

the full code is now

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import random
import time
measurements = ['abc','bcd','afr','reg','wow']
counter = 0
figure = pyplot.figure()
measurement_frame = pd.DataFrame(index = measurements)
def get_live(counter2, col_num):
    measurement_frame.iat[counter2,col_num] = random.randint(50,80)
def add_to_dataframe():
    global measurement_frame
    #timey = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    timey = datetime.now().time()
    if measurement_frame.shape[1] == 6:
        measurement_frame.drop(measurement_frame.columns[0], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    measurement_frame[timey] = measurements
    col_num = measurement_frame.shape[1]-1
    print(col_num)
    counter2 = 0
    for item in measurements:
        t = threading.Thread(target=get_live, args=(counter2, col_num,))
        t.start()
        counter2 = counter2 +1
    t.join()
    print(measurement_frame.columns[0])
    time.sleep(1)
def update(frame):
    add_to_dataframe()
    x_data = measurement_frame.columns
    print(x_data[0])
    y1_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[0]]
    y2_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[1]]
    y3_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[2]]
    y4_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[3]]
    y5_data = measurement_frame.loc[measurement_frame.index[4]]
    line, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y1_data, '-', color = 'b')
    line2, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y2_data, '-', color = 'g')
    line3, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y3_data, '-', color = 'r')
    line4, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y4_data, '-', color = 'm')
    line5, = pyplot.plot_date(x_data, y5_data, '-', color = 'y')
    line.set_data(x_data, y1_data)
    line2.set_data(x_data, y2_data)
    line3.set_data(x_data, y3_data)
    line4.set_data(x_data, y4_data)
    line5.set_data(x_data, y5_data)
    figure.gca().set_xlim(left =x_data[0], right = datetime.now().time())
    print(figure.gca().get_xlim())
    return line, line2, line3, line4, line5,
animation = FuncAnimation(figure, update, interval=1000)
pyplot.show()
```